# ngx-bootstrap datepicker validate invalid date

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

When an invalid date is entered, I want to save or keep the value entered so I can display it to the user. How do I do this?

**Background**:  I'm using the ngx-bootstrap v5.1.0 datepicker and angular 7.2.15. When a date is invalid (ex:09/99/2020 using MM/DD/YYYY), it automatically puts the string "Invalid date" into the input box when I leave the input field.

This technique works but additionally, I'd like to give the user some sort of feedback about the date that they entered. Specifically, the value  entered is invalid. In this case, it would be 09/99/2020.

I can get the invalid date validation to fire, but I can't get the value of the date originally entered so the user knows what they entered and why it's invalid.

[image]

How do I get or keep the original value entered into the field? I've tried an onChange event and `valueChanges` but the `ngx-datepicker` seems to override this so it doesn't fire until you leave the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngx-bootstrap-datepicker has a custom Output event `bsValueChange`

Add the output to your HTML `input` element:

```
  <input type="text"
        class="form-control"
        [minDate]="minDate"
        [maxDate]="maxDate"
        #dp="bsDatepicker"
        (bsValueChange)="onDateChange($event)"
        bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="myDateValue">
```

and then handle this in your component ts:

```
 myDateValue: Date;
  previousDate: Date;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myDateValue = new Date();
  }

  onDateChange(newDate: Date) {
    this.previousDate = new Date(newDate);
```

Example stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-taconz

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that it had the custom Output event so that is very helpful. I still want to provide the feedback that if a user entered 9/99/2020 then it tells them that is what they entered. Example: "Invalid Date, you entered 9/99/2020". 


Because the type is a date, the invalid date in your stackblitz example always shows, Wed Dec 31 1969 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) because the actual date value is a null.


I need to capture the string and I'm not sure how/if I can do that?

Comment: @Sandy There won't be an easy way to do this. Since the bsDatepicker automatically applies null to dates that are typed and can't be converted into a standard date (defaults to 0 when creating a date from it which is where that date comes from). You could do this by applying a keyup event handler `(keyup)=updateText($event)` and then manually updating a string to track this, but you'll like hit various errors when doing this.

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well but thought I'd check. Thank you for the response.